# system image files

Tags: windows-7

if you were to back up windows 7 with an system image file on a portable HDD, can you boot your computer from said system image file after a full single partition reformatting? or for that matter boot another computer from said image file?

Answer (score 0):

What are using to create the system image.  I'm guessing here the answer is no.  I know you can do this with firewire on a Mac and you can do this with a Live Linux on USB.

As for boot another computer that's even more unlikely, because of the way windows does device drivers and the HAL.

Answer (score 0):

If you backed up the drive to an image file like an iso it is not bootable because Windows will not be able to find the necessary files to read and boot from.

You will nit be able to boot another pc from the image for the same reason but also that Since Windows 2000 (I believe) the windows installation creates a hardware profile when you install as an anti piracy measure. This is also why you can't take a windows hard drive out of one pc and put it into another pc and boot it up.